# Como faço para receber emails na minha aplicação web?

Tags: node.js, api, servidor, email, nodemailer

Estou fazendo uma aplicação web(front-end em VueJS/Quasar e servidor em HapiJS) e preciso que ela além de enviar também receba emails. Estou fazendo o envio através da biblioteca NodeMailer, e isso está funcionando sem problemas. Para que ocorra o recebimento o que eu preciso fazer?? Usar API?? Criar um servidor no Google Cloud Platform e integrar com a API do Gmail?? Onde encontro bons tutoriais para isso?? Sou iniciante em programação, peço desculpas se a pergunta parecer sem sentido, porém estou com muita dificuldade nessa tarefa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Descobri que não preciso criar servidor na nuvem nem nada disso, tudo o que eu preciso é criar um serviço de recebimento POP ou IMAP, dependendo de qual vai se encaixar melhor na necessidade. Para envio pode-se usar a biblioteca NodeMailer, para recebimento estou usando a node-imap, e para fazer o parse dos email quando pego eles do Gmail usando o node-imap, eu uso o mailParser, que é do mesmo criador do NodeMailer. Apenas quero compartilhar esse conhecimento com que futuramente pode ter a mesma dúvida que eu e acabe vindo parar aqui em suas procuras pela internet.